# iText Text Expansion Not Working in Certain Conditions

Tags: itext

The following code will generate a pdf that will not use the specified text expansions when read out loud. It seems that adding the image in a container is causing the problem.

```
void Main()
{
    using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 72, 72, 72, 72);
        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms);
        writer.SetTagged();
        doc.Open();

        var c1 = new Chunk("ABC");
        c1.SetTextExpansion("the alphabet");
        var p1 = new Paragraph();
        p1.Add(c1);
        doc.Add(p1);

        // Adding this image to the document as img > chunk > doc  causes the text expansion not to work.
        // Adding this image to the document as img > doc works
        var t = writer.DirectContent.CreateTemplate(6, 6);
        t.SetLineWidth(1f);
        t.Circle(3f, 3f, 1.5f);
        t.SetGrayFill(0);
        t.FillStroke();
        var i = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(t);
        var c2 = new Chunk(i, 0, 0);
        doc.Add(c2);

        var c3 = new Chunk("foobar");
        c3.SetTextExpansion("foo bar");
        var p3 = new Paragraph();
        p3.Add(c3);
        doc.Add(p3);

        doc.Close();
        ms.Flush();
        File.WriteAllBytes("d:\\expansion.pdf", ms.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Is this just me doing something wrong or a bug?

Comment: I don't know a lot about marked content but looking at the raw PDF stream I can see that your example code produces nested `BDC` and `EMC` code which I don't think is valid.

Comment: @ChrisHaas *Marked-content sequences may be nested one within another* (section 14.6.1 Marked Content / General of the PDF specification).

Comment: Thanks @mkl, I stand corrected!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this doesn't read out loud correctly in Adobe Reader, it does in JAWS. So it sounds like this is a reader issue and not necessarily an iText issue.